# Win 8.1 blue screen crash. Now won't boot to USB setup

Tags: windows-8.1, setup, usb-boot

I was browsing the web when Windows 8.1 pro froze. Then there was a blue screen with sad face emoticon saying a problem had been encountered and needed to restart.

After the restart it attempted to repair / restore but crashed and restarted again. Then I tried to boot from USB loaded with Win 8.1 pro setup. The Win 8.1 "fish" icon appeared on screen but setup was never entered. Instead a blue screen appeared saying File:\windows\setup32\boot\winload.exe could not be loaded. Even if all hard drives are disabled in BIOS leaving only USB it still doesn't enter setup and it still gives the error saying it can't load winload.exe.

what could be the cause of this breakage? Why is setup on the USB not being entered? How can this be fixed?

my motherboard is an ASUS P7P55D.

Many Thanks!

Comment: This is most likely a hardware issue and it's hard to diagnose with this information. Could be RAM, CPU, mobo, power supply, loose cable, ... you need basic hardware troubleshooting skills to debug and find the culprit. Check for any error codes in the bluescreen (take a pic if you don't have the time to note or remember) and google it or repost here.

Comment: Another idea is to check with a Linux Live CD. If it boots, you can use some tools to check what problems you may have with your hardware (e.g. burn-in tests, ...). UBCD has plenty tools as well for initial troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks Jakke. I've figured it out. Even though the POST LEDs were saying that the RAM was fine and it was showing in the BIOS it seems on of my 2 DIMMs has become faulty.